# Bad access displaying circle on Google Map

Tags: ios, google-maps

the `c.map = self.map` line fails with **EXC_BAD_ACCESS.**

From documentation:

```
/**
 * The map this overlay is on. Setting this property will add the overlay to the
 * map. Setting it to nil removes this overlay from the map. An overlay may be
 * active on at most one map at any given time.
 */
@property(nonatomic, weak) GMSMapView *GMS_NULLABLE_PTR map;

- (void)showResult:(GMSPlace *)place {
    self.place = place;

    GMSCameraPosition *position = [[GMSCameraPosition alloc] initWithTarget:place.coordinate zoom:16 bearing:0 viewingAngle:0];
    [self.map setCamera:position];

    GMSCircle *c = [[GMSCircle alloc] init];
    c.radius = 75 * 1609.344;
    c.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];
    c.map = self.map;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the position of `GMSCircle` with `CLLocationCoordinate2D` like this

```
c.position = coordinate; // Some CLLocationCoordinate2D position
c.map = self.map
```

Also give `fillColor` with less `alpha` so it display map also. 
Hope this will help you.